# Unable to access a scaled webapp in a docker swarm node worker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to test docker-swarm on Windows to better understand how the clustering works. I started off with a simple enough image yeasy/simple-web and have tested this out on AWS and Azure etc..

My current use case is on my local laptop which has Windows 7. Here are the steps I followed :

a) Setup a small 3 node docker swarm with one master and 2 worker nodes using `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox`...
So I have 3 docker machines with the ip addr's of 192.168.99.100-102. The manager is what I init'ed on the ...100 node. The worker1 on 101 and worker2 on 102.

b) Docker run the "simple-web" image with same port mapping on each of the nodes - master, worker1 and worker2 e.g., using a port mapping of `-p 8080:80`. I am able to access the webapp on each of the nodes using a web browser/curl local to that docker-machine.

c) Create a service on the swarm master node using the following syntax:

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --publish 8080:80 --name simple-web-svc yeasy/simple-web
```

The service shows up on a `docker service ls` output. The replica count of one was set so that I try to get the container running on the master node and which did happen. I can access this replica using a web browser. I then went on to scale out to 2 replicas, which was also successful as per `docker service ls`. However, when I try to access the 2nd replica (ip addr 192.168.101) using a web browser it doesn't work. (I figured the swarm node on which the container was running by doing a `docker ps` on each of the swarm nodes and figuring out where the 2 replicas were running; also `docker service ps <service_name>` provides this in a handy manner)

My `docker info` looks like this :

```
$docker info
Containers: 21
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 20
Images: 20
Server Version: 1.12.3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 265
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: overlay host bridge null
Swarm: active
 NodeID: d0hve121x3o122ozcegi9tmo0
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 81mfgps70olf4iz8z6fmh8umf
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 192.168.99.100
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.27-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.12.3 (TCL 7.2); HEAD : 7fc7575 - Thu Oct 27 17:23:17
UTC 2016
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.8 MiB
Name: default
ID: DDYX:XPK5:2FMG:JHTX:LDMS:XFUX:WPON:XJJH:6HXZ:E7MK:4OJP:SR22
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 43
 Goroutines: 149
 System Time: 2017-10-28T00:38:42.587703951Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Please let me know if more/other detailed command output is required.

Here is some *additional* cmd exec output (I increased replica count to 2 so I don't need to scale up +1 later):

```
docker@default:~$ docker service create --replicas 2 --publish 8080:80 --name simple-web yeasy/simple-web
afhnoixa2vzv3ge54iaoqk2m3
docker@default:~$ docker service ls
ID            NAME        REPLICAS  IMAGE             COMMAND
afhnoixa2vzv  simple-web  2/2       yeasy/simple-web
docker@default:~$

docker@default:~$ docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME        STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
4vl5qyxec60bj91o8fw5okkf0    swarm-worker-1  Ready   Active
a8u9807p0t5lquhyednsqrxih    swarm-worker-2  Ready   Active
d0hve121x3o122ozcegi9tmo0 *  default         Ready   Active        Leader

docker@default:~$ docker service ps simple-web
ID                         NAME          IMAGE             NODE            DESIRED ST
ATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR
2kvb48m0buxc4hfzx2trii10v  simple-web.1  yeasy/simple-web  default         Running
     Running 10 minutes ago
e2c977pexnre7p99wmqz2ii1x  simple-web.2  yeasy/simple-web  swarm-worker-1  Running
     Running 10 minutes ago


docker@default:~$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                            DRIVER              SCOPE
554c408f4141        bridge                          bridge              local

afa4c8525a33        cqrsesmsspringboot_default      bridge              local

224b86b82b0c        docker_gwbridge                 bridge              local

1fab35dc310a        host                            host                local

928etnvuhg8x        ingress                         overlay             swarm

e7afc71b2102        none                            null                local

28123e9e93a7        postgresdockercluster_cluster   bridge              local

docker@default:~$ docker network inspect ingress
[
    {
        "Name": "ingress",
        "Id": "928etnvuhg8xun0dql5ig8r2f",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.255.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "10.255.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {
            "b3f07b13f2da7d20bc10af38cc161e545b6d254ef5bfc62ec4fd85ecf0aa8c4c": {
                "Name": "simple-web.1.2kvb48m0buxc4hfzx2trii10v",
                "EndpointID": "00b70edabd6f5211f1b417ea70b7118ad0cbd12e2a49d20af80715
e03096624c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:ff:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ingress-sbox": {
                "Name": "ingress-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "0fa7119756f1e76308ba419236231267e1ab6a2caf6d1593fce42e
c5c75a8e16",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:ff:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "256"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Here are some screenshots of the browser behavior:
[image: Request 1]
[image: Request 2]

Can someone help me debug this and make it work ?

TIA.

p.s. I tried doing an overlay network and here is the level of success I have had :

```
docker@default:~$ docker service rm simple-web
simple-web
docker@default:~$ docker service create --replicas 1 --network myoverlaynw --publish 8080:80 --name simple-web yeasy/simple-web
0s3070f4dw8itxwxtouoe9oys
docker@default:~$ docker service ls
ID            NAME        REPLICAS  IMAGE             COMMAND
0s3070f4dw8i  simple-web  0/1       yeasy/simple-web
docker@default:~$ docker service ps simple-web
ID              NAME            IMAGE           NODE        DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE            ERROR
cn5rzl4as1oo7gftwhixea72n   simple-web.1        yeasy/simple-web    swarm-worker-2  Running         Running 8 seconds ago
dqq15nua3i8kgkpmlkwx2t77i       \_ simple-web.1     yeasy/simple-web    swarm-worker-1  Shutdown        Rejected 18 seconds ago  "Failed to find a load balance."
eqny9gczipwpq45jd0zhtzqov       \_ simple-web.1     yeasy/simple-web    swarm-worker-2  Shutdown        Rejected 18 seconds ago  "Failed to find a load balance."
docker@default:~$
```

Comment: What do you mean with: does not work? could you please clarify the error.

Comment: @opHASnoNAME  I am able to open 192.168.99.100:8080 in a web browser and see then web content. I am unable to open 192.168.99.101 and /or 192.168.99.102 in a web browser. I assume since the default endpoint-mode is vip, all requests are being handled @ the swarm-master node ie 192.168.99.100. If this is true, then everything works, but for the content I am seeing in the vip e/p which lists 10.255.0.6 and 10.255.0.7 alternatively for multiple consecutive http requests. My local ip address listed on this webapp (simple-web) is 10.255.0.3. Might be there is a better way for me to test this ?

Comment: I have added some more detail and made some updates where needed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your services in a overlay network:

```
docker network create -d overlay my_network
```

If you now start the 3 services inside this network like this:

```
docker service create --replicas 2 --network my_network --publish 8080:80 --name simple-web yeasy/simple-web
```

When all replicas are up, you should be able to access the webservice on every SWARM-IP on Port 8080.

[From Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#if-the-manager-cannot-resolve-the-tag):

> You can rely on the routing mesh. When you publish a service port, the
>   swarm makes the service accessible at the target port on every node,
>   regardless of whether there is a task for the service running on that
>   node or not. This is less complex and is the right choice for many
>   types of services.

Comment: Can you check the postscript of my question ? I did indicate trying out the overlay network, but getting an error `"Failed to find a load balance."` on each of the worker nodes. Thanks for helping me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was using different docker versions. just check your docker versions in swarm workers and manager. I also upgraded all docker version to 18.03.1-ce.

( sometimes this will not the answer for your question since you are using VMs. I was working with different servers.)

Hope this will help